# A locus problem related to the parabola $y^2=4x$ and the line $y=x+2$

Tags: geometry

Consider any point P on the line $y=x+2$ and the parabola $y^2=4x$.Let $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ be the point of contact of the tangents from P on the parabola.Find the locus of midpoint of $Q_1Q_2$.

I know how to solve this problem using synthetic results like $SS_1=T^2$ and other results using chord of contact and etc.Can someone provide a solution using the basics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps:

1. Write the slope of the tangent to the parabola at point $(x_0,y_0)$ in terms of $y_0$. You should get $2/y_0$.
2. Write the slope of the line that connects $(x_0,y_0)$ on the parabola, and the point $(x_p,y_p)$ on the line, and equate it with the slope of the tangent
   $$\frac{y_p-y_0}{x_p-x_0}=\frac2{y_0}$$
3. Use $$y_p=x_p+2\\\frac14y_0^2=x_0$$Write $y_0$ in terms of $x_p$. You should obtain a simple quadratic equation, that has some nice roots, $y_{0,\pm}$.
4. Calculate $x_{0,\pm}=\frac14y_{0,\pm}^2$
5. Calculate the midpoint

Let me know if something is not clear, or if you have difficulties with any of the steps.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach.

Let $P=(t,t+2)$, $Q=(u^2,2u)$ (parametric equations of line and parabola).

Then slope of $PQ$ is $k=\frac{2u-t-2}{u^2-t}$.

Tangents have minimum or maximum slope along various $u$, then for tangents $\frac{dk}{du}=0$.

Taking derivative and factorizing gives $u^2-(t+2)u+t=0$.

Middle of $Q_1Q_2$ is $M=\left(\frac{u_1^2+u_2^2}{2},\frac{2u_1+2u_2}{2}\right)$.

Using Vieta's theorem: $u_1+u_2=t+2$, $u_1u_2=t$, then $u_1^2+u_2^2=(t+2)^2-2t=t^2+2t+4$.

$M=\left(\frac{u_1^2+u_2^2}{2},u_1+u_2\right)=(t^2+2t+4,t+2)$

Changing parameter $t+2=v$, then $M=((v-2)^2+2(v-2)+4,v)=(v^2-2v+4,v)$, which locus is parabola $x=y^2-2y+4$.